# My SQL workbench creating many to many relationship in EER diagram

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

so I was trying to create an EER diagram from a database model and I wanted to do something similar to this.

Say I have a table named Bag and another one named Address. I already set the PK in Address to be the FK in Bag, when creating the diagram I found that I cannot find the option "many to many" in mySQL workbench. [image: see the screenshot I took]

I wonder what is causing this to happen(maybe I'm doing something wrong but right now I cannot think of any reasonable explanation...)

Hopefully someone can shed some light on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Usually many to many relationship would have an additional table to create the relationship -

- Address ( table holds addresses )
- AddressBag ( tableholds the many to many  the bags to addresses relationship with FK to address and FK to bags)
- Bag ( table holds the bags )

Answer (score 0):

`Many2Many relationship` need an additional table to define the relationship between two tables. This table holds the `FK` to each of the two or more tables. If we want to get the data, just need to select columns by this relationship.  Wish this would help you.